# Adding columns to h2o datasets using h2o.cbind

Tags: r, h2o

I have a data frame in H2O (called df1.hex) and I am trying to add new columns to this data frame using h2o.cbind. I am using h2o 3.18.0.4.

The code that I have shown below is only a simplified version of what I am trying to do. In reality, I am adding new columns to the df1.hex data frame based on various conditions. The bottomline is that I would like to be able to use 'h2o.cbind' whenever I need to append new columns to df1.hex. So, I would have to call h2o.cbind multiple times during my program. The real dataset that I am operating on is too big for me to do all this in R and then export it into h2o.

Consider the code below:

```
# Let's load H2O and start up an H2O cluster
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# Initialize a data frame with a column 'y'
df1 = data.frame(y=c('A', 'B', 'C'))
df1.hex = as.h2o(df1)
print(df1.hex)

# Need to append additional columns to df1.hex named x1, x2 etc...
for (i in 1:2) {
  df2 = data.frame(x=c(1*i, 2*i, 3*i))
  colnames(df2) = c(paste("x", i, sep='')) # x1, x2 etc...
  df2.hex = as.h2o(df2)
  print(paste("Iteration: ", i, ": Adding df2.hex...", sep=''))
  print(df2.hex)
  df1.hex = h2o.cbind(df1.hex, df2.hex) # Append x(i) to df1.hex data frame
}

print("The final dataset df1.hex: ")
print(df1.hex)

h2o.shutdown(prompt=FALSE)
```

The output is as follows:

```
> print(df1.hex)
      y
    1 A
    2 B
    3 C

[1] "Iteration: 1: Adding df2.hex..."
  x1
1  1
2  2
3  3

[1] "Iteration: 2: Adding df2.hex..."
  x2
1  2
2  4
3  6

[3 rows x 1 column] 

[1] "The final dataset df1.hex: "
> print(df1.hex)
  y x2 x20
1 A  2   2
2 B  4   4
3 C  6   6
```

Even though I was appending two new columns named x1 and x2, the final version of df1.hex contains two columns named x2 and x20. Why did that happen?

Also, the x1 column completely disappeared. I only see the column x2 appearing twice.

How can I fix my code to name my columns x1 and x2 and have the correct values in those columns as I originally intended?

Thanks.

Karthik.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that the the `cbind` is only binding the last run element, basically, resulting in two 'x2' columns and by making it unique the column names could have changed to 'x20'.  One approach would be to assign it to a `list` and then `cbind`.

```
#initialize a `list` of length 2 
lst <- vector("list", 2)

for (i in 1:2) {
  #create the h2o dataset and assign it to each list element      
  lst[[i]] <- as.h2o(data.frame(x=c(1*i, 2*i, 3*i)))
  #change the column names of the h2o dataset
  names(lst[[i]]) <- paste0("x", i)        
}

#do the cbind outside the loop
do.call(h2o.cbind, c(df1.hex, lst))
#  y x1 x2
#1 A  1  2
#2 B  2  4
#3 C  3  6

#[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

---

Or this can be done in pipe (`%>%`) with `tidyverse` function

```
library(tidyverse)
map(1:2, ~ tibble(x = (1:3) * .x) %>% 
                set_names(., paste0("x", .x)) %>% 
                as.h2o) %>%
         append(df1.hex, .) %>%
         do.call(h2o.cbind, .)
#   y x1 x2
#1 A  1  2
#2 B  2  4
#3 C  3  6

#[3 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: The above mentioned workaround does work. The code that I provided above is a simplified version of what I am actually trying to do. In my real application, I have to call h2o.cbind multiple times based on various conditions. Is there another workaround that can accomodate that constraint?

Comment: Also, I am curious why h2o.cbind is actually behaving that way.

Comment: @Karthik Could you update the post with how you are using the function.

Comment: I just updated my original post to add some clarity on how I am using h2o.cbind.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I was able to resolve the issue.

I just replaced the following code in my original post:

```
  df1.hex = h2o.cbind(df1.hex, df2.hex) # Append x(i) to df1.hex data frame
```

with this...

```
  x.hex = h2o.cbind(df1.hex, df2.hex)
  df1.hex = h2o.assign(x.hex, 'df1')
```

I am not sure, but it may have something to do with how h2o stores data internally.

The full code is shown below:

```
# Let's load H2O and start up an H2O cluster
library(h2o)
h2o.init()

# Initialize a data frame with a column 'y'
df1 = data.frame(y=c('A', 'B', 'C'))
df1.hex = as.h2o(df1)
print(df1.hex)

# Need to append additional columns to df1.hex named x1, x2 etc...
for (i in 1:2) {
  df2 = data.frame(x=c(1*i, 2*i, 3*i))
  colnames(df2) = c(paste("x", i, sep='')) # x1, x2 etc...
  df2.hex = as.h2o(df2)
  print(paste("Iteration: ", i, ": Adding df2.hex...", sep=''))
  print(df2.hex)
  # df1.hex = h2o.cbind(df1.hex, df2.hex) # Append x(i) to df1.hex data frame
  x.hex = h2o.cbind(df1.hex, df2.hex)
  df1.hex = h2o.assign(x.hex, 'df1')
}

print("The final dataset df1.hex: ")
print(df1.hex)

h2o.shutdown(prompt=FALSE)
```

Now, I do get the desired output:

```
> print("The final dataset df1.hex: ")
[1] "The final dataset df1.hex: "
> print(df1.hex)
  y x1 x2
1 A  1  2
2 B  2  4
3 C  3  6

[3 rows x 3 columns] 
>
```

Cheers!

Karthik

Comment: Glad that you  were able to resolve.  Sorry, I got busy and couldn't check your comment earlier